# Isolated scope access other scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive with an isoleted scope, but in scope property of directive I put the code:

```
parentController: "="
```

In the html of my custom directive I put:

```
< my-directive data-parent-controller="controllerName.controller">
```

In my controller I have the variable controller that receive "this" as your value.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function(){
    this.controller = this;
    this.screenObject = {};
});
```

In the directive I need to renderize some tag element like:

```
<pre> < input type="text" data-ng-model="directive.parentController.screenObject.property /> </pre>
```

When I change value of the element the other not change.

This is possible ?
If this is possible, what can I have to do ?

Obs: screenObject have the properties that I use in screen like:

```
 screenObject.code
```

```
 screenObject.descryption
```

Comment: why do you need isolated scope if the only scope item passed to it is the controller? Removing the isolated scope, directive would already be in parent controller scope. If it's a deep nesting issue you could use a service

Comment: My html form is generated by a javascript function a json.
I do it to keep compatibility with the old code

Comment: I found my error, in the html I put "directive.parentController", but parentController was declared in the scope, so the html must be "parentController"